# How can I apply some animation for list of images in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a card game using python pygame I want when the game start the cards  move one by one from the center to left and right just one time .
How can I apply some animation for list of images in pygame
I did it for one image it worked well but I don't know how to do it with list of images any help thanks

```
from enum import Enum
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
import pygame
import random

type=Enum('type','Heart Diamond Club Spade')
value=Enum('value','2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A')

class Card(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,type,value,screen) :
        super(Card,self).__init__()
        self.card_type=type
        self.card_value=value
        self.screen=screen
        self.imgpath='./Resources/'+str(self.card_value.name)+' '+str(self.card_type.name)+'.jpg'
        self.card_img=pygame.image.load(self.imgpath)
        self.card_img=pygame.transform.scale(self.card_img, (70, 95))
        self.card_img.convert()
        self.card_rect=self.card_img.get_rect()
        

    def __str__(self) :
        txt=str(self.card_value.name)+' '+str(self.card_type.name)
        return txt

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        if self.card_type==__o.card_type and self.card_value==__o.card_value:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __lt__(self,__o:object) -> bool:
        if self.card_type==__o.card_type and int(self.card_value.value)<int(__o.card_value.value):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __gt__(self,__o:object) -> bool:
        if self.card_type==__o.card_type and int(self.card_value.value)>int(__o.card_value.value):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def blitme(self,x,y):
        self.card_rect.x=x
        self.card_rect.y=y
        self.screen.blit(self.card_img,self.card_rect)
        
    
        

def get_Deck(screen):
        cardlist=list()
        for t in type:
            for v in value:
                c=Card(t,v,screen)
                cardlist.append(c)
        random.shuffle(cardlist)
        return cardlist   

def deal(deck,cardNum):
    cardlist=list()
    for i in range(cardNum):
        c=random.choice(deck)
        deck.remove(c)
        cardlist.append(c)
    cardlist=sorted(cardlist,key=lambda x:(x.card_type.value,x.card_value.value) ) 
    return cardlist
        
class Player():
    def __init__(self,rank,screen) -> None:
        self.name=None
        self.hand=None
        self.score=None
        self.rank=rank
        self.screen=screen

    def draw_cards(self):
        screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rank==0:
            x=screen_rect.left+((screen_rect.width-975)/2)
            y=screen_rect.bottom-100
            for c in self.hand:
                c.card_rect.bottom=screen_rect.bottom
                c.x=x
                c.blitme(x,c.card_rect.y)
                x+=75    
    
    def cards_animation(self):
        for c in self.hand:
            c.card_rect.x-=10



[![image description][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1NbQ.png
```

Comment: Could we get the other portions of your program such as the "get_Deck()" function?  Thanks.

Comment: OK sir I hope you can help

Comment: Looks like I need some missing data definition.  I got an error on the statement "for t in type:".  My terminal barked at me with the error "TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable".  I'm guessing there is a list or data frame containing card values and suits.

Comment: This the whole code sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with your code, while trying to assimilate what you ultimately wanted to do with moving and animation.  What it seemed like was needed was an additional function to perform a redraw of your images which performed different location setting as opposed to the draw function which basically was resetting every position back to the initial spots.

In the initiation of the player hands, the program could call the draw function.

```
    players[0].draw_cards()
```

The down in the "while" loop, the program would then call the redraw function instead.

```
        screen.fill((3,99,14))
        players[0].redraw_cards()
        players[0].cards_animation()
```

The redraw function would be a slimmed down version of the draw function.

```
    def redraw_cards(self):
        for c in self.hand:
            c.blitme(c.card_rect.x,c.card_rect.y)
```

For what it might be worth, here is a copy of your code with my tweaks.  You can analyze it and if I went off on a tangent, just dispose of it.

```
from enum import Enum
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
import pygame
import random
import sys

type=Enum('type','hearts diamonds clubs spades')
value=Enum('value','2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 jack queen king ace')

class Card(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,type,value,screen) :
        super(Card,self).__init__()
        self.card_type=type
        self.card_value=value
        self.screen=screen
        self.imgpath='/home/craig/images/PNG-cards-1.3/' + str(self.card_value.name)+'_of_' + str(self.card_type.name) +'.png'
        self.card_img=pygame.image.load(self.imgpath)
        self.card_img=pygame.transform.scale(self.card_img, (70, 95))
        self.card_img.convert()
        self.card_rect=self.card_img.get_rect()
        
    def __str__(self) :
        txt=str(self.card_value.name)+' '+str(self.card_type.name)
        return txt

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        if self.card_type==__o.card_type and self.card_value==__o.card_value:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __lt__(self,__o:object) -> bool:
        if self.card_type==__o.card_type and int(self.card_value.value)<int(__o.card_value.value):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __gt__(self,__o:object) -> bool:
        if self.card_type==__o.card_type and int(self.card_value.value)>int(__o.card_value.value):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def blitme(self,x,y):
        self.card_rect.x = x
        self.card_rect.y = y
        self.screen.blit(self.card_img,self.card_rect)

def get_Deck(screen):
        cardlist=list()
        for t in type:
            for v in value:
                c=Card(t,v,screen)
                cardlist.append(c)
        random.shuffle(cardlist)
        return cardlist   

def deal(deck,cardNum):
    cardlist=list()
    for i in range(cardNum):
        c=random.choice(deck)
        deck.remove(c)
        cardlist.append(c)
    cardlist=sorted(cardlist,key=lambda x:(x.card_type.value,x.card_value.value) ) 
    return cardlist
        
class Player():
    def __init__(self,rank,screen) -> None:
        self.name=None
        self.hand=None
        self.score=None
        self.rank=rank
        self.screen=screen

    def draw_cards(self):
        screen_rect=self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rank==0:
            x=screen_rect.left+((screen_rect.width-975)/2)
            y=screen_rect.bottom-120
            for c in self.hand:
                c.card_rect.bottom=screen_rect.bottom
                c.x=x
                c.blitme(x,y)
                x+=75    
        if self.rank==1:
            x=screen_rect.left+((screen_rect.width-975)/2)
            y=screen_rect.top + 20
            for c in self.hand:
                c.card_rect.top=screen_rect.top
                c.x=x
                c.blitme(x,y)
                x+=75    
        if self.rank==2:
            x= 80
            y=screen_rect.top + 20
            for c in self.hand:
                c.card_rect.top=screen_rect.top
                c.x=x
                c.blitme(x,y)
                y+=75    
                
    def redraw_cards(self):
        for c in self.hand:
            c.blitme(c.card_rect.x,c.card_rect.y) 
    
    def cards_animation(self):
        for c in self.hand:
            c.card_rect.x += 2
            if c.card_rect.x > 1400:
                c.card_rect.x = 40
            
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    infoObject=pygame.display.Info()
    w=infoObject.current_w-100
    h=infoObject.current_h-100
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
    screen.fill((3,99,14))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Game1')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    # card1=Card(type['Club'],value['7'],screen)
    # card1.blitme(card1.card_rect.x,card1.card_rect.y)
    deck=get_Deck(screen)
    players=list()
    for i in range(4):
        p=Player(i,screen)
        p.hand=deal(deck,13)
        players.append(p)
    players[0].draw_cards()
    players[1].draw_cards()
    players[2].draw_cards()
    x = 0
    y = 0
    moving = False
    while True:
        clock.tick(4800)  
        screen.fill((3,99,14))
        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        players[0].redraw_cards()
        players[1].redraw_cards()
        players[2].redraw_cards()
        if (x != 0 and y !=0):
            players[0].hand[8].blitme(x,y) 
            x = 0
            y = 0
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                moving = True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                moving = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and moving:
                x, y = event.pos
                
        screen.fill((3,99,14))
        players[0].redraw_cards()
        players[0].cards_animation()
        players[1].redraw_cards()
        players[1].cards_animation()
        players[2].redraw_cards()
        players[2].cards_animation()
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

FYI, I had to hunt down a different set of open source card images so you would want to revert to your code for the card class.

Comment: Thanks sir your solution is benefit and so close to what I need :)

Comment: Glad to help.  I wish you the best on your game.  Regards,

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options you have. If this is an animation that happens before the game starts, don't include it in the main game loop and instead have it run before then. Put the images into a list in the order you want them displayed. Then, iterate over that list and display each image. You'll also need where the positions of each item will be, either one position if they don't move or a list of positions. An example might look like this

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

list_of_images = ...
framerate = ...  # control how fast the animation goes

pos = ...  # (x, y) where all images will be displayed at, otherwise make it a list

for image in list_of_images:
    clock.tick(framerate)
   
    screen.fill(color)
    screen.blit(image, pos)
    # display everything else needed

# main event loop
```

If you have a list of positions that go with the image, have `for image, pos in zip(image_list, positions):`

This could all also be done inside the main game loop, if you add some sort of condition to check whether or not the animation is active or not, and keep track of what frame it's on.